# How do I fetch user data from firebase without being logged in?

Tags: javascript, firebase

I made a blog which has a database structure as shown below

```
users:{
    $uid:{
        Posts:{
            $post_id: {...}
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to have a public page where everybody can read the post without being logged in.
How do I fetch the data from firebase as it's clear I need the user id to go deeper

Comment: I'd say auto-login as default user who only has basic read priviledges?

Comment: `".read": true, ".write: false"` as your database rules

Comment: I have the rules set up that way but I'm looking for a way to get the uid so I could get the path to the post I want to fetch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the structure to the following:

```
users
  uid
    name : john
    age : 100
posts
  postId
     userId : uid
     post: post_content
```

Then you can do the following:

```
let ref = firebase.database().ref("posts");

ref.on("value", ((snapshot) => {
 snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
  let childData = childSnapshot.val();
  console.log(childData.post);
 });
});
```

`childData.post` will contain all the posts under `posts` node.